# Analog Electronics Circuit

Tags: transistors, bjt

I am trying to solve this problem but I have failed.
These are 2 BJTs:
1.Assume V1=2V, what is the value of VE?
2.Assume V1=-4.5V, what is the value of VE?
[image: Question Circuit]

Actually I do not understand how to deal with 2 transistors in the same circuit, so any explanation would be very useful.
Thanks.

Comment: Hint: you have a positive voltage on the left and a GND on the right. What possible way can the current flow?

Comment: Of course from +ve voltage to GND.

Comment: So in the first case the lower transistor is in cut off mode isn't it?

Comment: Initially, you should assume \$VE\$ is grounded (= 0V) and no current is flowing from \$V1\$.  Now try Step 1 knowing what \$V_{BE}\$ is for each transistor, and determine which one is on.  Then it's a simple voltage divider (minus a voltage drop).  Repeat for Step 2.

Comment: This is called a bipolar voltage follower with typical emitter follower drops.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is homework, I'm not going to outright answer it.

First go look up something known as a *emitter follower* and understand it.  Note that you have two emitter followers, one capable of driving the output high, the other low.

To not get confused by the two transistors, start by analyzing with only one in the circuit at a time.  Assume V1 is 2 V and the bottom transistor isn't there.  What happens.  Now add the bottom transistor.  How does that change things, if at all?

Comment: Thanks to your help, I found that when V1 = 2V; IB for the upper transistor is +ve so it is on and IB for the lower transistor is -ve so it is off, and when V1 = -4.5V; IB for the upper transistor is -ve so it is off and IB for the lower transistor is +ve so it is on. Then after turning off one transistor we know the circuit reduces to Emitter-Bias circuit and we apply KVL to find the currents and voltages. But could you tell please, this approach is applicable for every circuit contains more than one transistor?

Comment: @O-BL: It seems you understand this circuit.  No, you can't count on the same approach working with any two-transistor circuit.  Instead of looking for canned analysis methods, you should be trying to understand each circuit by looking at what each part does.  With understanding, there is no need for cookbook approaches.